# Do all mysqli PHP functions have mysqli or do some have just mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I just learned that there are two types(?) of mySQL functions--mysql and mysqli.  On w3schools, only the mysql functions are included in their PHP section http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysql.asp.  If I was to turn a mysql function into a mysqli function, could I just add on the 'i' ?  For instance, for the function mysql_select_db(), would I just change it to mysqli_select_db() to get that same function in the mysqli version?

If yes, are there any mysql functions where I couldn't do this?

And finally, are there any mysqli functions that don't have a mysql equivalent and is there an up-to-date list of them anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mysqli_*` functions provided by the `mysqli` PHP module are a superset of the `mysql_*` functions. They supersede and replace the `mysql` module, though both are available on most servers for compatibility reasons. `mysqli` stands for MySQL Improved.

In reality, you should be using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) for any new code, not either of these sets of functions.

For your information despite this:

- [`mysql_*` function list](http://php.net/mysql)
- [`mysqli_*` function list](http://php.net/mysqli)

Re: W3 Schools, please [have a read of this site](http://w3fools.com/). They are quite correct about a lot of things, including the poor PHP tutorials at W3 Schools. [The PHP documention at php.net](http://php.net/docs.php) is very comprehensive, always up to date and in most cases very good.

Comment: I'm not really sure I know the implications of being a superset so I still can't figure out if I can just change mysql_* functions to mysqli_*.  I also heard that you can't use both mysql and mysqli functions.  So I'm confused.  Is there any way that you can answer my questions more directly?  Thank you.

Comment: @Sam A superset means that every `mysql` function has a (deprecated) `mysqli` function, but the reverse is not always true. I've also expanded the answer with function lists for both modules from the official PHP documentation. You **should** be using PDO though, not either of these sets of functions. Using PDO makes your code automatically work for other database systems than mysql simply by changing the connection string (ignoring slight variances in SQL dialects which can cause issues sometimes)

Comment: Ok, I guess that means I have to go back to the drawing board.  Thanks for the links and your explanations!

Comment: @Sam the documentation on php.net is really good. You should try reading through that before trying to find other information.